# SQLAlchemy: What is the essence that the same session is accessed within one thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, sqlalchemy

Example code:

```
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
session1 = Session()
session2 = Session()
session1 is session2 # => True
```

In SQLAlchemy, `scoped_session` have 2 effects:

1. Different threads get different session.
2. The same session is returned when you call `Session()`.

Question:
I understand that Effect 1 avoid difference threads operating on the same session which may lead to race condition(am I right?). But what is the essence of Effect 2 (or why do we want the same session within one thread)?

Answer (score 1):

In one thread, only one session can access DB, flush, commit, and close at the same time. And then the next one. So in this case, one session is enough. Then let's make it singleton.

Comment: What is the potential side-effect / harm / cost if I use multiple sessions in one thread?

Comment: I don't think there is some harm or cost. In python, all commands or codes is executed synchronized, so it is just needless to be multi-sessions.